# Android: Remove view from superview

Tags: android

How do I remove a View from its superview? In iOS it's performed by sending `removeFromSuperview` to the view that should be removed.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [`getParent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getParent()) to get the parent of the `View`, then call [`removeView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeView(android.view.View)) on it.

```
View yourView = ...;
ViewGroup viewParent = (ViewGroup) yourView.getParent();
viewParent.removeView(yourView);
```

Comment: @Jonny Yeah, it's odd. `View` has `findView*` methods, but that's it. Even `ViewParent` is restricted. Everything has to be done from a `ViewGroup` or subclass thereof.